# How set buffer with sqlite with c#

Tags: c#, sqlite, buffer

I use https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net,

a sqlite wrapper for c#.

I use sqlite as cache on disk to serialize some images.
Most of the time I save an Image and I read a lot of times, 
but every time sqlite read from disk and not buffered image, so I have a lot operation of IO

so I can bufferize last images read and avoid too many IO operation, but I wonder if sqlite have already this features... as many other db

thanks

Comment: It's quite unclear what you want, first you say you want SQLite to save your data to disk but it's failing, then you say you want to use a memory buffer instead of using disk IO?

Comment: ok sorry I edit to explain me better